# communication between flex AS3 and asterisk server?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, ubuntu, cross-domain, asterisk

I'm trying to upload a file using Flex to an Ubuntu server running asterisk.  The server-side upload code looks correct; when I test it locally it successfully uploads the file to the server.

When I deploy the solution to our main server it doesn't upload the file.  Debug mode shows an error: `crossdomain.xml could not be found.`

I have a crossdomain file, but I don't know where to put it. The main server is at 192.168.1.143, and the Ubuntu server is at 192.168.1.137.
After some reading I found it should be accessed from 192.168.1.137:8088/crossdomain.xml.

Where do I need to put the crossdomain.xml file on the Ubuntu server?

Answer (score 1):

The crossdomain.xml file will be search on your webserver main page, which is on port 80 of the server you're trying to connect.

If you're using Apache, lighttpd, or others, and don't use a VirtualHost, chances are your must put your file at `/var/www/crossdomain.xml`.

You must be able to access it using `http://192.168.1.137/crossdomain.xml`, without any port indication.